# ColdFusion: Storing tags inside database outputs as string

Tags: database, coldfusion, evaluate

I am creating a CMS system which has a rewrite rule to use only one page. From that page I am then pulling the content from a database to populate each page based on its url. This all works fine, however, on some pages I also want to use ColdFusion tags that are stored in the database tables i.e. `<cfif>` etc.

When the page renders it outputs the tags as html instead of ColdFusion running the tag. I found a way to get it working by using `Evaluate()` around the content. However, reading up on this apparently has massive performance issues.

I was therefore wondering what other options I could use to get this working.

Comment: This question has been asked before - I don't have a URL handy, and don't see it in "related", but there's definitely (at least one) question on this subject.

Comment: Also - _"i am creating a cms system"_ - **don't**. Save yourself a lot of time and **use [Mura](http://getmura.com)** (or any existing CMS) which has already solved over 95% of the problems you're going to encounter.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Peter, i did try looking for this alot yesterday and came up with some answers, none which worked for me unfortunately. When i said a CMS system, i meant a basic one page template that is pulling the content from a database. Nothing much more than that. any other comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write the data to a file and then use `<cfinclude>` to include it on your page

Untested, but something like this should work.

```
<cfset NewFileName = CreateUUID()&'.cfm'>
<cffile action="write" file="YourPath\#NewFileName#" output="#DatabaseInfo#">
<cfinclude template="#NewFileName#">
<cffile action="delete" file="YourPath\#NewFileName#">
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, i went down this route yesterday as alot of people recommended it, however each time i tried it still output as html rather than Coldfusion.

Comment: can you post the code you were using along with the output you were receiving?

Comment: No need Matt, just found the flaw in my original code for your recommendation and got it working. Before, i was enclosing the template in a cfoutput tag and putting only the code in the database i.e. #now()#. I have now changed it so that the cfoutput tag is also inside the database and it now works. Thanks for your help on this.